# Как верстать?

Tags: html, css

Помню была такая статья про весртку, как называется не помню там описывалось про правило наименования классов стилей и т.п

> h-bar__wrape

Подскажите ссылку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

БЭМ (Блок - Элемент - Модификатор)

[ru.bem.info](http://ru.bem.info)

Answer (score 3):

Советую [Google HTML/CSS Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml)